# How to show that the topology co-induced in $\mathbb{S}^1 |_{\sim} $ gives us a homeomorphic space with the circle

Tags: general-topology

How do I show that the topology co-induced from projection in $ \mathbb{S}^1 |_{\sim} $ gives us a homeomorphic space with the circle. Where $ \sim $ is an equivalence relation given with

$$ (x_1, y_1) \sim (x_2, y_2) \Leftrightarrow x_1 - x_2 \in \mathbb{Z} \land y_1 - y_2 \in \mathbb{Z} $$

My idea was first to find a homeomorphism from $ \mathbb{S}^1|_{\sim} $ to the interval $[0, 1)$ and then I know that there exists a homeomorphism from $[0, 1)$ to the circle. However I am having troubles to concretize and exhibit my idea. Thank you in advance.